# Saving date data in Laravel migrate (Excel to mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, excel, laravel, migrate

When I tried to save the dates in my Excel file to the database with datetime/timestamp, it gave an error  said it was in the wrong format.

if opened and updated be datetime,error is:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '44839.319074074' for column `it-graph`.`backlogs`.`opened` at row 1
```

I wanted to get it as a string, I thought it would show the dates as they are, but different numbers came out.

It's my migrate :

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('backlogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('number');
        $table->string('opened');
        $table->string('updated');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->string('caller');
        $table->string('configuration');
        $table->string('state');
        $table->string('creatorGroup');
        $table->string('assignmentGroup')->nullable();
        $table->string('assignedTo')->nullable();
        $table->string('priority');
        $table->string('updatedBy');
        $table->float('elapsedPercentage',8,2);
    });
}
```

And then view of mysql database date (it's look different):
[database view here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrrKJ.png)

Finally,the format I want it to load (excel file)
[excel view here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4NJP.png)

With which data type can I capture this format? Can I capture data from Excel column correctly?
YYYY.MM.DD HH:MM:SS

Controller excel import Code:

```
function importData(Request $request){

   $the_file = $request->file('uploaded_file');
   try{
       $spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($the_file->getRealPath());
       $sheet        = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
       $row_limit    = $sheet->getHighestDataRow();
       $column_limit = $sheet->getHighestDataColumn();
       $row_range    = range( 2, $row_limit );
       $column_range = range( 'M', $column_limit );
       $startcount = 2;
       $data = array();
       foreach ( $row_range as $row ) {
           $data[] = [
               'number' =>$sheet->getCell( 'A' . $row )->getValue(),
               'opened' => $sheet->getCell( 'B' . $row )->getValue(),
               'updated' => $sheet->getCell( 'C' . $row )->getValue(),
               'description' => $sheet->getCell( 'D' . $row )->getValue(),
               'caller' => $sheet->getCell( 'E' . $row )->getValue(),
               'configuration' =>$sheet->getCell( 'F' . $row )->getValue(),
               'state' =>$sheet->getCell( 'G' . $row )->getValue(),
               'creatorGroup' =>$sheet->getCell( 'H' . $row )->getValue(),
               'assignmentGroup' =>$sheet->getCell( 'I' . $row )->getValue(),
               'assignedTo' =>$sheet->getCell( 'J' . $row )->getValue(),
               'priority' =>$sheet->getCell( 'K' . $row )->getValue(),
               'updatedBy' =>$sheet->getCell( 'L' . $row )->getValue(),
               'elapsedPercentage' =>$sheet->getCell( 'M' . $row )->getValue(),
           ];
           $startcount++;
       }
       DB::table('backlogs')->insert($data);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
       $error_code = $e->errorInfo[1];
       return back()->withErrors('There was a problem uploading the data!');
   }
   return back()->withSuccess('Great! Data has been successfully uploaded.');
```

}

Comment: and how you're saving the excel data to DB? Add that part of the code

Comment: I've edited the post, we can look @OMiShah

Comment: also add your complete sheet structure and sample data

Comment: Did you mean excel ? or .blade.php views @OMiShah

Answer (score 0):

```
       foreach ( $row_range as $row ) {
       $data[] = [
           'number' =>$sheet->getCell( 'A' . $row )->getValue(),
           'opened' => PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($sheet->getCell( 'B' . $row)->getValue()),
           'updated' => $sheet->getCell( 'C' . $row )->getValue(),
           'description' => $sheet->getCell( 'D' . $row )->getValue(),
           'caller' => $sheet->getCell( 'E' . $row )->getValue(),
           'configuration' =>$sheet->getCell( 'F' . $row )->getValue(),
           'state' =>$sheet->getCell( 'G' . $row )->getValue(),
           'creatorGroup' =>$sheet->getCell( 'H' . $row )->getValue(),
           'assignmentGroup' =>$sheet->getCell( 'I' . $row )->getValue(),
           'assignedTo' =>$sheet->getCell( 'J' . $row )->getValue(),
           'priority' =>$sheet->getCell( 'K' . $row )->getValue(),
           'updatedBy' =>$sheet->getCell( 'L' . $row )->getValue(),
           'elapsedPercentage' =>$sheet->getCell( 'M' . $row )->getValue(),
       ];
       $startcount++;
   }
```